# Equivalent of @Named API parameter in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there any way to used named method parameter in Python - corresponding to this Java example:

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "foos.remove",
    path = "foos/{id}",
    httpMethod = HttpMethod.DELETE,
)
public void removeFoo(@Named("id") String id) {
}
```

In my Python version, if I set the `@endpoints.method` path to `foos/{id}` the URL gets matched correctly, but how do I access the parameter?

Comment: It should just be the first parameter to your method.

Comment: @Linuxios that does not apply to the Python implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not strict equivalent, but if `{id}` is in your path, then there must be a field called `id` in the `protorpc` message class you use for the request class in the method.

For example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote

class MyMessageClass(messages.Message):
  id = messages.StringField(1)  # Or any other field type

@endpoints.api(...)
class MyApi(remote.Service):
  @endpoints.method(MyMessageClass, SomeResponseClass,
                    ..., path='foos/{id}')
  def my_method(self, request):
    ...
```

Comment: This works, thank you! It would be good if it was mentioned in the docs.